# Идёя расчёта силовых линий прямой

Tags: matplotlib, vector

Создаю программу для отрисовки векторных полей(электростатических). Уже написал функцию и смог реализовать расчёт поля для точечных зарядов, но хочу также добавить возможность отрисовки поля для прямых линий. Сначала решил просто разбивать прямую на несколько точечных, делить заряд и рассчитывать для каждого точечного, но такой подход оказался очень ресурсозатратным. Как можно рассчитывать векторные поля для прямых?
P.s. Использую matplotlib, но будет достаточно, если поможете хотя бы с идеей или алгоритмом.